# Complex list rendering with ngFor and tabs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

I'm wondering how to quickly display a list of complex element I'm working with.
I have list of entities with 20ish properties each, and I'm building a list that uses maybe half of each:

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of getCurrentList()" class="fadeIn">
        <ion-item-sliding>
            <ion-item button no-padding lines="none" (click)="showDetail(item.id)">
                <ion-thumbnail slot="start" class="collectionThumb">
                    <img-loader class="gameImg" [src]="item.image.S80"></img-loader>
                </ion-thumbnail>
                <ion-label>
                    <h2 text-wrap>{{item.title}} ({{item.edition}})</h2>
                    <progress-bar [progress]="getFloatNote(item.rating)"></progress-bar>
                    <ion-chip color="primary">
                        <ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>{{item.players_min}} - {{item.players_max}}</ion-label>
                    </ion-chip>
                    <ion-chip color="primary">
                        <ion-icon src="../assets/icon/cake.svg"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>{{item.age_min}}+</ion-label>
                    </ion-chip>
                    <ion-chip color="primary">
                        <ion-icon name="time"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-label>{{item.duration}}'</ion-label>
                    </ion-chip>
                </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options *ngIf="currentTab == 'collection'">
                <ion-item-option (click)="deleteItem(item)" color="danger">
                    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash"></ion-icon>
                </ion-item-option>

                <ion-item-option (click)="editNoteModal(item)" color="secondary">
                    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="create"></ion-icon>
                </ion-item-option>
                <ion-item-option (click)="addPlayModal(item)" color="tertiary">
                    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" src="../assets/icon/dice.svg"></ion-icon>
                </ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
        </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-card>
```

I have 2 different lists with no overlapping elements that are to be displayed with the same template, and I use tabs to switch between them (Collection <-> Wishlist)
When I clic on a tab, the change event modify a "currentTab" property and Angular magic gets the new list with "getCurrentList()"

```
 <ion-segment color="primary" (ionChange)="switchList($event)">
        <ion-segment-button checked value="collection" class="segmentButton">
            <ion-label>Collection
                <ion-badge color="medium">{{boardGames.filteredCollection.length}}</ion-badge>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="wishlist" class="segmentButton">
            <ion-label>Wishlist
                <ion-badge color="medium">{{boardGames.filteredWishList.length}}</ion-badge>
            </ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>


 public getCurrentList(): BoardGame[] {
    if (this.currentTab == 'collection') {
      return this.boardGames.filteredCollection;
    } else {
      return this.boardGames.filteredWishList;
    }
  }
```

So, All of this is working quite fine with up to 40 elements, but over that it starts to get cranky.
First the ripple effect on the tab looks buggy, the effect is triggered after a few seconds and lags when the list becomes around 100 elements, and it gets worse and worse with higher numbers.
I have another view of the same elements but only with the image and the title, that displays a lot faster.

I tried to change the event on the `<ion-segment>` for an individual `(click)` on each buttons, but didn't change the display problem.

As you can see I'm using ionic framework but I don't think this is the problem here.

What I'd like to know is :

- Is the list i'm trying to build is too complex to be smooth ?
- Would making the `<ion-card>` a component improve performance ?
- Am I swapping the two lists in a terrible way ??
- Is there a way to make sure the ripple effect is first rendered, then
  the calculation of the list would happen afterward : I could add a
  spinner in the content and that would look OK even if takes some time
- Would it be best if I created a kind of observable that would send
  the lists elements progressively ?

Well I'm open minded please help !!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after digging a little further, ionic framework provides the ready made answer to this:    `<ion-virtual-scroll>`[Ionic Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll)

It simply handle the rendering of enough elements to fill the view given an array of elements. So whatever the length of the list is has no importance, the perfs are now great !

Anyway I'd like to have an opinion on the list swapping method and the component solution, would that improve perfs ?